# ESX Blade unable to contact NAS

Tags: vmware-esx, network-attached-storage

I have 3 blades configured with ESX, on one of this blades I am unable to get ESX to connect to a NAS data store, I get the error:

```
NFS Error: unable to Mount filesystem: Unable to connect to NFS server
```

The strange thing here is that the other 2 blades can connect to this NAS, also this blade can connect to another NAS (used for backup) which is on the same switch, going through the same VMKernal port and NIC.

Any ideas?

The NAS is an IOMEGA StoreCenter Pro

Comment: Just to double-check: The backup-NAS that you connect to fine is on the same IP subnet as the NAS you can't connect to?

Comment: Also, try to use ping and vmkping to make sure that you have network connectivity (that no firewalls are blocking you)

Comment: Can you do a brain-dump for me of everything please (blade make/model/interconnects/adapters, exact esx version, network setup, NAS details - everything basically).

Comment: @ErikP Yep, backup NAS is on the same subnet, have done a ping and vmkping and both get a reply.
@Chopper, I will get that added for you shortly.

Comment: Sam, there's a firmware update (2.0.11.42072) that says it fixes NFS issues, no details and there's a more recent update but I'd rather you know sooner rather than later.

Comment: Huh, weird. I don't know what you should try as the next step, but as a last resort I'd restart the switch to make sure that this isnt some weird MAC-table problems (i've had similar problems with ESX vlan trunking and iSCSI, switch reboot was my only solution).

Comment: To add to Erik's comment I'd be tempted to restart everything (man I sound like dell's tech support first line :) )

Comment: lol, yeah i'll give that a go, if it doesn't work I'll try the firmware upgrade over the weekend.

Comment: "Have you checked if the power cable is inserted firmly?" Haha. Happy weekend Sam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, its working now. The problem was that the NAS could not resolve the ESX blade by name. Why this was an issue i'm not sure as, we were connecting by IP, and the other blades worked ok, but hey its working now.

Comment: Excellent work, Great Job!

Comment: Very useful to know, it's not the sort of thing you'd expect to be an issue.